# JNI access object field with generic type

Tags: kotlin, generics, java-native-interface

I have a generic class that looks somewhat like this:

```kotlin
public class Foo<T>(arg: T) {
    var bar = arg
}
```

What type signature should I use to get `fieldID` of `bar` in C?

```c
const jclass Foo = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
const jfieldID barID = env->GetFieldID(Foo, "bar", "???");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics are erased, so they are just objects.

If it would be like this:

```
public class A<T extends Runnable> {
    T t;
}
```

The signature would be `Ljava/lang/Runnable;`

In this case, as it isn't bound:

```
Ljava/lang/Object;
```

Comment: This is probably another topic, but how then I cast `Ljava/lang/Number;` to `Int`?

Comment: Use the method `intValue()`(Defined in java/lang/Number) (If you mean the primitive int, sorry I have no idea of kotlin). If you mean the object Integer (java/lang/Integer), you have to do nothing, if you can assert that this object is really an Integer, not some other number